# Using IO::Async with vectorized STDIN

Tags: multithreading, perl, io

I have a multi-threaded program, in the main thread it waits for input from STDIN (forever)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use IO::Async::Timer::Periodic;
use IO::Async::Loop;
use IO::Async::Handle;


my ($rin, $rout) = ('', '');
vec ($rin, fileno(STDIN), 1) = 1;

my $loop = IO::Async::Loop->new;
my $handle = IO::Async::Handle->new(
    handle => $rin,

    on_read_ready  => sub {
        say 'Ready read';
    },
);

$loop->add( $handle );
$loop->run;
```

Before switching to IO::Async, I use builtin `select` call on `$rin`, and that works just fine.

Now the module complains about `$rin`, the error was `Expected that read_handle can ->fileno at wait.pl line 20.`

So, what should I pass in? Or is there any other threads implementation that works better?

P.S The builtin perl threads module keeps crashing, I can't use that

Comment: Could you maybe explain what you mean by “*vectorized STDIN*”? I have never heard such a term, and think you may be mis-applying the `vec` function here.

Comment: @amon I'm writing a audisp replacement for `auditd` program something like this http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/audit-rt-events.txt in C language

Comment: @amon search for this `Get header first. it is fixed size` once you opened that page

Comment: “vector” is another name for “array”. This does not mean that Perl's `vec` function should be used when porting that C code. It would be more useful to read about [`readv` and `struct iovec`](http://man.cx/readv). A `readv` call can be translated to multiple `read`s, which Perl also supports – but you might want to use `->read_exactly($len)` from [`IO::Async::Stream`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Async::Stream#f-stream-read_exactly-len) instead. To get data from a string representing a C struct, use the `unpack` function.

Answer (score 4):

The handle should be a file handle and not a vector, e.g. use `\*STDIN` (and read the documentation which clearly describes this). And IO::Async is the complete opposite to threads, e.g. it is an event driven model with non-blocking I/O (which scales much better, definitly compared to perl threads). There are several others like this, AnyEvent and POE probably being the most popular.

Comment: Hmm, how should I use vectorized stdin then ..? I can't change that, the program that feeds it uses vectorized input

Comment: There is no such thing as "vectorized input". If you only have the file descriptor number instead of the file handle you might use open to create a new file handle from the number (see perldoc perlopentut and search for "file descriptor number"), but its better to use the original file handle, e.g. the one you use to read and write.

Comment: Indeed - I am confused by this notion of "vectorized input". I think you are being confused by the `vec()` function, which is commonly used in conjunction with `select()` as a means to manipulate the bit-vector (hence the name) that `select` will use to keep the read/write/exceptional filehandles in.

Answer (score 2):

When creating an `IO::Async::Handle`, the `handle` argument to the constructor must be an IO object, or something that responds to a `fileno` method. If you want to use `STDIN`, you could do something like

```
my $handle = IO::Async::Handle->new(handle => *STDIN{IO}, on_read_ready => sub { … });
```

The real question here is what the hell you are trying to do with `vec`. The `vec` function is a way to treat a string as a very C-like piece of memory. It has the following signature:

```
vec $string, $offset, $bits
```

which treats the contents of `$string` as an array of elements with size `$bits`, of which you are accessing the `$offset`-th entry. As `STDIN` has the fileno zero, you will be setting the first bit in that string `$rin` to one. A simpler way to phrase this is to use `pack`:

```
$rin = pack "b", 1;
```

which incidentally is the same as `$rin = chr 1` or `$rin = "\x01"`. Such a string is not useful as an object, a number, or as a filehandle.